# Creating Static library using GCC

Tags: gcc

When I am compiling code using GCC, it is giving two outputs .o and .d file.
While creating library(.a) do I need to add(.d) files also. If yes then how?

Comment: `gcc` usually gives only one output `.o`. You agglomerate these with `ar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you only need to add the .o file, a static library archive is just a collection of .o files.

The .d file is a makefile fragment for specifying the dependencies used to build the object file, and is only needed when you are compiling the .o file itself.